# What is diffrence between lock() and expired()? weak_ptr C++

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

Recently I started at C++11.
I studied about `weak_ptr`. There exist two ways of getting raw pointer.

1. `lock()` function

   ```
   shared_ptr<Foo> spFoo = wpPtr.lock();

   if(spFoo) {
       spFoo->DoSomething();
   }
   ```
2. `expired()` function

   ```
   if(!wpPtr.expired())
   {
       shared_ptr<Foo> spFoo = wpPtr.lock();
       spFoo->DoSomething();
   }
   ```

Which is the better way? What is different between the two ways?

Comment: As others have said, you must use 1 to avoid a race. And to be concise, consider `if (auto spFoo = wpFoo.lock()) {` since then (short of an else block) nobody can access spFoo if it’s nullptr.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

So shared ptr and weak ptr are thread safe, in that if you have an instance of the object local to a given thread, and they share a common pointed-to object, you can interact with them in one thread and another and everything works.

For this to work properly, you have to use them properly.

`wp.expired()` is only useful to do things like "remove every expired weak ptr from a buffer".  It is not useful for the purpose you put it.

Every weak pointer, once expired, remains expired.  But an engaged weak pointer can become expired immediately after you verify it is engaged.

```
if(!wpPtr.expired())  {
  // <<--- here
  shared_ptr<Foo> spFoo = wpPtr.lock();
  spFoo->DoSomething();
}
```

At `<<--- here` we know *nothing* about the state of `wpPtr` in a multi-threaded environment.  It could be expired or not expired.  On the other hand:

```
if(wpPtr.expired())  {
  // <<--- there
}
```

At `<<--- there` we *do* know the weak pointer is expired.

Like with file io and other kinds of "transactional" operations, the only way to check if you can do something is *try to do it*.  Between determining you should be able to do it and doing it, the state could change and the operation could fail.

You can sometimes work out that you almost certainly *could not do it* early, which is sometimes useful, but you cannot be certain you can do it until you try.  The attempt to try can fail, at which point you handle the error.

```
if(auto spFoo = wpPtr.lock())  {
  spFoo->DoSomething();
}
```

this is the "right" way to interact with a weak pointer.  Test for the validity of the weak pointer and get the shared pointer in the same operation.

Creating a `spFoo` outside of the `if()` header is acceptable, I prefer this technique as the scope of the `spFoo` is limited exactly to the zone where it is valid.

The other preferred technique is early exit:

```
auto spFoo = wpPtr.lock();

if(!spFoo) return error("wp empty");

spFoo->DoSomething();
```

which makes the "expected" execution of the code flow in a flat line without indentation or conditions or jumps.

Answer (score 8):

Below are the relevant operations for a `weak_ptr`. You should go with **option 1** because approach 2 is not thread-safe.

> `w.use_count()` The number of `shared_ptr`s that share ownership with `w`
>
> `w.expired()` returns `true` if `w.use_count()` is zero, `false` otherwise
>
> `w.lock()` If `expired` is `true`, returns a null `shared_ptr`; otherwise returns a `shared_ptr` to the object to which `w` points.

**(2) Not thread-safe**

```
// let p be the last shared_ptr pointing at the same object as wpPtr
if (!wpPtr.expired())
{
    // we enter the if-statement because wpPtr.use_count() is 1
    // p goes out of scope on its thread, the object gets deleted
    shared_ptr<Foo> spFoo = wpPtr.lock(); // null shared_ptr
    spFoo->DoSomething(); // ERROR! deferencing null pointer
}
```

**(1) Thread-safe**

```
// let p be the last shared_ptr pointing at the same object as wpPtr
shared_ptr<Foo> spFoo = wpPtr.lock();
// now, wpPtr.use_count() is 2, because spFoo and p are both pointing at the object
// p goes out of scope on its thread, but spFoo is still pointing at the object
if(spFoo) {
    spFoo->DoSomething(); // OK! safe to dereference
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The second variant has two problems:

1. It does an unnecessary check `wpPtr.expired()`
2. It is missing a necessary check `if (spFoo)` before dereferencing `spFoo`

The first variant is transactional, and is the one to use when you ultimately need to work with the object referred to by the weak pointer.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**.

If you go with option 2 then between calling `wpPtr.expired()` and calling `wpPtr.lock()` the `weak_ptr` could have expired and the line `spFoo->DoSomething()` will try to dereference a null `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock):

`std::weak::lock` effectively returns

```
expired() ? shared_ptr<T>() : shared_ptr<T>(*this)
```

use expired to check whether the underlying object is valid and lock to potentially promote the object to a `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: You dropped the important part of the quote.  Which makes your quote so false I went to check to see how to fix cppreference.  It turned out it was just your quoting that was wrong.

Comment: I agree with Yakk. Indeed, the _crucial_ point on cppreference is that the line you reported is executed *atomically*. That's why option 2 in the original question is only ok in a non-threaded context.