# Update if not Expired on Weak Pointer in Multi-Threaded Context

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

The **client** holds a shared pointer to a value say `double`, and a **server** updates this value on another detached thread by holding a `weak_pointer`, the server checks if the `weak_pointer` is expired and if it is not, it is deleted from a safe vector. I suspect this would not work as the `shared_ptr` could be destructed from the client side **between** my read of `expired()` (which I think is thread safe as I imagine it refers to the atomic counter of `shared_ptr`) **and** my update of the value. Is there a way to have the check `expired()` and a `lambda` function updating the value before it is destructed please? I mean:

```
struct server
{
public:
    static void subscribe(const std::shared_ptr<double>& d)
    {
        m_values.safe_push_back(d); //safely pushes back in the vector
    }

    void update()
    {
        auto updater = [](std::weak_ptr<double>& wd)
        {
            if(wd.expired()) wd = nullptr;
            else *wd += 2.0; //This is not thread safe I guess?
        };
        m_values.safe_remove_all(nullptr);
        m_values.safe_visit(updater);
    };

private:
    static safe_vector<std::weak_ptr<double>> m_values;
}
```

```
struct client
{
    void subcribe_sleep_print(const double random_seconds)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<double> d = std::make_shared<double>(0.0); //for the sake of the example assume we create subscribe before sleep
        server::subscribe(d);
        sleep_for_seconds(random_seconds); //sleeps for some random time in seconds.
        std::cout << *d << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Imagine `server::update` and `client::subcribe_sleep_print` are running on different threads. This is not safe as the `shared_ptr` might get destructed while the server is writing? Is there a way to this with no user (me) defined atomics or mutexes? I don't mind if it's used in the background as long as I don't add them (atomic/mutex) myself as I know the shared pointer uses an atomic counter already.

**EDIT**: I am not using double in my program, I am using a thread safe object :) So the operation += can be assumed thread safe. Sorry.

Comment: Curious the term `*wd` would even compile - a `std::weak_ptr<T>` doesn't even have (and never should have) an `operator*` defined to protect you against this type of error?

Comment: You didn't hack the `std::weak_ptr` template just to get `m_values.safe_remove_all(nullptr);` working - did you?

Comment: I did, I will clean..

Comment: You should give the `safe_vector` a `safe_remove_if` instead to deal with this type of cleanup.

Comment: *"if it is not [expired], it is deleted from a safe vector"* -- Backwards? Don't you want to delete the pointers that **are** expired?

Comment: @SpeakX And if you want to reduce contention of the mutex inside `safe_vector` - consider to have `safe_remove_if` return the ***moved*** elements to the caller, so they are finally deallocated outside of the critical section. You will otherwise find that you have a high cost for heap memory management inside your critical section as it frequently ends up releasing the last instance of the shared pointers control block.

Comment: *So the operation += can be assumed thread safe. Sorry.* but in the code you write `//This is not thread safe I guess?` .... Consider to use `std::atomic<double>` when `double` is just supposed to be a placholder for the actual type in your real code that is not relevant for the question you ask

Comment: it is relevant, the safety of the pointer not on the double

Comment: Tough to tell from incomplete code, but this looks like an obfuscated version of either [operator -> or ->* applied to "const std::weak_ptr" instead of to a pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70364855) or [What is diffrence between lock() and expired()? weak_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37679636)

Comment: The question is whether or not the expression `*wd += 2.0;` is safe in the given context, assuming `+= 2.0` is safe. So the question boils down to asking if the expression `*wd` is safe. This expression uses a non-standard `operator*` whose definition is not provided. After thinking about this, if I were to provide an implementation that is not inherently broken, the expression would be safe (but possibly have subtly different semantics than expected). Others might come up with an implementation that is not safe. So I've come to the conclusion that this is not answerable in its current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>         else *wd += 2.0; //This is not thread safe I guess?
> ```

No, it's not thread-safe. You are facing a race-condition where the pointer may expire after all just after you have checked for expiration. In that case, you have now dereferenced a `nullptr`.

So the way to go is to explictly use `std::weak_ptr<T>::lock()` to try and obtain the associated shared pointer (which is also what `expired()` did internally), and only if that obtained a valid pointer you may do a read- or write-access.

If you didn't obtain a valid shared pointer, treat it just as if `expired()` had returned false.

> ```
>    m_values.safe_remove_all(nullptr);
>    m_values.safe_visit(updater);
> ```

I'm certain you've got the order wrong. You had intended to first update, and then weed out the `nullptr` your update callback had produced.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the ordering! Will lock() allocate anything on the heap please?

Comment: @SpeakX No, `lock()` will not allocate anything (other than the `std::shared_ptr` on the stack). It only attempts to increase the use-count.

Comment: *"it's not thread-safe."* -- Depends on your point of view. Since the code does not compile, it's as safe as any other non-compiling code...

Comment: @JaMiT It compiles, with a little piece of extra code he didn't show to extend `std::weak_ptr` by an unsafe `operator *` and `operator==`, as well as a somewhat common implementation of a `template class safe_vector<T>` . I know, the complete code isn't shown. But the missing parts are easy enough to extrapolate.

Comment: @Ext3h *"extra code he didn't show to extend `std::weak_ptr`"* -- modifying the standard library is undefined behavior. So from one perspective, as long as that code is in place, nothing is thread safe, that includes both the initial code and your version.

Comment: @JaMiT Not when he implemented the operators as free standing functions outside the `std` namespace. Still perfectly well defined behavior - the race condition aside.

Comment: @JaMiT that's note the goal! We are not touching c++ for the first time.. The question is more on the concept not the compilation? Should include sleep function implementation or should I include the safe_vector here? Sometimes helping getting the answer is easier by not complicatin stuff...

Comment: @SpeakX *"Should include sleep function implementation or should I include the safe_vector here"* -- If they are necessary for the code, then yes. If you can replace them with standard functions (like `std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);`), then do that. (I suspect much of your custom coding could be omitted while preserving the essence of the question.) A [mre] should be complete enough to be copied and compiled. The details you leave out could be the key to the problem.

Comment: @Ext3h weak_ptr doesn't give access to the underlying pointer so its not possible to write that function without a lock and go via a shared_ptr anyway [and then returning the raw pointer and letting the shared_pointer expire which is frankly stupid]. So I'm with JaMiT here. That function basically can't exist in any reasonable codebase.

Comment: It is a custom weak pointer, when I see my code, I indeed call lock

Comment: @MikeVine Right - and exactly that issue where the pointer expired was the actual content of the question.